# Delete rows with multiple where condition

Tags: magento-1.7

I need to delete one or multiple rows from my table with where condition.

Eg: 1. Delete from search where id=1 and customerid=2

EG: 2. Delete from search where customerid=2

After some browsing found this code and added to my model

```
public function deleteByCondition($id,$uid)
{
  $table = $this->getMainTable(); 
  $result = $this->_getWriteAdapter->delete($table,array('id'=>$id,'customerid'=>$uid));
}
```

But it didn't help. Then got another code which didn't help either.

```
public function deleteByCondition($id,$uid)
{
  $table = $this->getMainTable(); 
  $where =  $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?  AND',$id).$this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto("$customerid = ? ", $uid);
  $result = $this->_getWriteAdapter->delete($table,array('id'=>$id,'customerid'=>$uid),$where);
}
```

I know we can execute the raw sql query but am thinking there must be other way to do coz i think its not the proper way to open the write connection any where and update DB.

Now i need to delete with where condition. can someone help ?

Answer (score 4):

Inside model class write following code

```
public function deleteByCondition($id,$uid)
{
    return $this->getResource()->deleteByCondition($id,$uid);
}
```

Inside resource model class write following code

```
public function deleteByCondition($id,$uid)
{
  $table = $this->getMainTable();
  $where = array();
  $where[] =  $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto('`id` = ?',$id);
  $where[] =  $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto('`customer_id` = ?', $uid);
  $result = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete($table,$where);
  return $result;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: On my controller i have this code. 
$del = Mage::getModel('savesearch/savesearch')->getResource(); $del->deleteByCondition($savid,$customerData);
And added your code to the resource model. But didn't work. And am sure am receiving all the params.

Comment: From controller you should try following way..

Mage::getModel('savesearch/savesearch')->deleteByCondition(‌​$id,$customer_id)

Comment: No dude it didn't help either. It didn't throw any error in log. And also didn't delete the value from db. just redirected to my page.

Answer (score 4):

What if you try something like:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('your/collection')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_1', 'valuex')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_2', 'valuex');
$collection->walk('delete');
```